# Pandas Pivot table aggregation

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

Need some help on pandas.

I have a dataframe in the format below. I need to find out what is the frequency BuySell and sum of PV across currencies.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to use `pivot_table`,try:

```
frequency_df=df.pivot_table(index=['Dealid','PVCcy'],columns='BuySell',aggfunc='count').reset_index()
sum_df=df.pivot_table(index=['Dealid'],aggfunc='sum').reset_index()
df_final=frequency_df.join(sum_df)
```

Comment: Hey, if you like this answer, can you also up-vote it please? Thanks!